# Java how to run another .jar program from code in response to button click

Tags: java

I have written a Java program that should open another program (which is a .jar file). If I use this code in the main class of my program, all works correctly:

```
File logFile = new File("./ePaymentUpdater.jar");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(logFile.getCanonicalFile());
//or
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ePaymentUpdater.jar");
```

But if I paste the same code in the event in response to the user clicking a button, it doesn't work as it should:
The program seems to run, because it creates a folder like it should be (this code is in the main class of the called program), but it doesn't show the jFrame it should

It seems that i cannot open a frame from inside the frame of another program...

This is my main class:

```
package prove_idiote;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

//        try {
//            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ePaymentUpdater.jar");
//        } catch (Exception e) {            
//            System.out.println(e);
//        }

        Tester tester = new Tester();
        tester.setVisible(true);       
    }   
}
```

And this is my button event:

```
private void ExecuteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "before" ,"ATTENZIONE!",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ePaymentUpdater.jar");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "after" ,"ATTENZIONE!",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    } catch (Exception e) {            
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work"! What happens when you execute that code in the event handler? Any error/messages?

Comment: Desktop.open() uses windows file associations for opening and executing programs. If they are not correctly set it will not work. Does the ePaymentUpdater.jar have a MANIFEST.MF file with main class set?

Comment: No error message, it simply seems that the .jar file called doesn't run
PS: i see now that the .jar DOES run, because it creates a folder as it should be, but it doesn't show what it should (a jForm)

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you process the event? It will help to test the code locally.

Comment: Is there some reason for this to run in a separate process than the one that launched your code?

Comment: I have edited with some code. I run it in a separate process because the called .jar is a db update process, wich has to be executed every night (scheduled), but the user can also run it when he desires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem (and the solution)
There were some missing libraries in the called .jar (i've put the two jars in the same folder, so they shared the same libs, but one of them was using a lib that was missing)

Thnaks for the hints

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Runtime class of java and process your jar from there as follows:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar ./ePaymentUpdater.jar")
```

Where `Runtime` handles all the processes at runtime and executes them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar yourjarfile")
```

Comment: I've also tried this road, but the result is the same:
works if launched in the main, doesn't work if launched in response to the button click